# Reading uploaded Excel file without saving it

Tags: c#, excel, file

In this snippet of code - I get the uploaded file from the user and save it in a folder in my app and then make OleDbConmnection to this Excel File and read the data. My question is - can someone suggest a way which is preferred of reading this excel file but without saving it previously and again as it's in my case fill the datatable with the data

```
   if (Request != null)
      {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
        if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
        {
          string fileName = file.FileName;
          string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
          string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName);


          if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
          {
            string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files[0].FileName;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
            {

              System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
            }
            Request.Files[0].SaveAs(fileLocation);
            string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
            fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            //connection String for xls file format.
            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
            {
              excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
              fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            //connection String for xlsx file format.
            else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
              excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
              fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            excelConnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
            OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            objAdapter1.Fill(ds);

            DataTable Dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this library.
[Excel Data Reader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

**EDIT** 
example:

```
if (Request != null)
{
   HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
   if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
   {
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
        string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName);

        if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
            IExcelDataReader excelReader;
            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            else
                excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            DataSet ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            DataTable Dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Where is defined the `stream` from `CreateBinaryReader(stream)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
```

Say that can't possible convert HttpPostedFile to HttpPostedFileBase