# Parse xml from request.file without saving in server

Tags: c#, xml, stream

I upload an xml file through `$.ajax post` as formdata to an mvc controller. Is it possible to parse the file without it being saved in some directory in the server.
My c# code is as below

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VersionXML()
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                /*--Can I exempt this if clause and do something for the parsing--*/
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Show_New_Content");
        }
```

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116791/reading-uploaded-excel-file-without-saving-it

Comment: yes you can do parsing before saving to server

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to parse with XML

**1)** You can load `InputStream` of your file to `XmlDocument` directly and process your xml,

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentType == "text/xml")
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(file.InputStream);

    //You can parse your xml here

    //Upload file code here       
}
```

**2)** You can also load `InputStream` of your file to `XDocument`,

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentType == "text/xml")
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(file.InputStream));

    //You can parse your xml here

    //Upload file code here       
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. may I know what exatly the difference in working of both these code?

Comment: With `XDocument` you can use Linq on it and `XmlDocument` you can parse your xml in traditional.

Comment: you can read more from here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542101/5514820, and  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d68f2bb-2195-4494-b0b1-54dc78aa56f0/xdocument-or-xmldocument?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: @Arvin, I think you forgot to view my answer. If it helps then mark the tick on left side of the answer to make it green :)